# minimising performance using pontrayagins maximum principle

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control, dynamic-programming

given that we want to minimize a performance

$$\min \int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}} L\big[x(t),u(t)\big ]\ \mathrm dt$$
subject to $$\dot{x} = f(x,u)$$
$$x(0) = x_{0}$$

when constructing the Hamiltonian would we first multiply L by negative one to make it a maximisation probelm? so $$H(x,u,\lambda) = -L + \lambda^{T}f(x,u)$$

I understand that when doing time minimization problems($L = 1$), you don't multiply by $-1$ cause time cannot be negative. Am I correct in doing this, multiplying $L$ by negative $1$ then using PMP?